# 39.829605 PKCS# signature not signed with a trusted key

Tags: lenovo, 18.10

I trying to start Ubuntu 18.10. When I try to start I receive this message:

> 39.829605 PKCS# signature not signed with a trusted key

I trying some boot options in BIOS - without result.

I have Lenovo IdeaPad 310
GPU & processor are AMD. I've found only answers for Nvidia drivers.

Comment: In your logs - is it `PKCS#` or `PKCS#7`

Comment: excuse me, i am blind. pkcs#7

Comment: What is the actual problem? For example, I have these messages in my logs as well, but there is no problem because of that.

Comment: This message means end of loading, It will stay on this line and nothing more will happen..

Comment: now i have "44.818177" number instead "39.829605" ....

Comment: The number is just the timestamp during boot at which it happens, it has nothing to do with the problem. If the boot fails, I would ask what changes you made just before this happened, e.g. any new drivers installed. You can also try to boot into recovery mode (hold down Shift during boot and select from the menu) to see if at least that works.

Comment: Recovery mode possible. Btw. i made probably apt-get upgrade... i think about, i have virtualbox..maybe some problem with secure boot..